# Install4J failure strategy, retry or quit on failure, remove ignore button

Tags: java, install4j

Using Install4J 6, I set the Failure Strategy of a particular Run Script action to be "Ask user whether to retry or quit". This is exactly what I want.

However, when the script runs and a failure occurs, the message box that pops up also contains a button to "Ignore".

[image]

Short of implementing my own options dialog using the Util.showOptionDialog(...), how do I remove this ignore button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update on 2021-01-14:**

Since install4j 6.1.6, you can define the installer variable

```
context.setVariable("sys.actionRetryDisableIgnore", true);
```

to remove the "Ignore button" from the confirmation dialog.

---

Old alternative answer:

This is currently not possible. I would recommend the following:

Set the "Failure strategy" property of the action to "Continue on failure" and call

```
context.setVariable("retryAction", Util.showOptionDialog("Your message",
    new String[] {"Retry", "Quit"}, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE) == 0);
```

in the case of failure or

```
context.setVariable("retryAction", false);
```

otherwise.

Then put the action into an action group. In the configuration of the action group, select the "Loop" property and set the "Loop expression" property to

```
context.getBooleanVariable("retryAction")
```

Comment: Seems like a very convoluted workaround for a problem that should have been corrected 5 years ago.

Comment: Actually, there is another way since 6.1.6. I've just updated the answer.